# Is there a way to get rid of the wrapping items property when an ApiMethod returns a Collection?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Api Method in a Google Cloud Endpoint module that returns a Collection. The method looks something like that:

```
@ApiMethod(name="listChildren")
public Collection<Child> listChildren() {
    Collection<Child> children = getChildren(); //call some method to build the collection
    return children;
}
```

When I look at the returned JSON response, my response looks something like that:

```
{
    "items": [
        { ... }, // first child
        { ... }, // second child
        ... // and so on
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get rid of the "items" property that wraps the items in my collection so that the JSON response is directly the array. I am looking to get a response looking more like following:

```
[
    { ... }, // first child
    { ... }, // second child
    ... // and so on
]
```

Is there a way to achieve that? I have looked through the Google Cloud Endpoints documentation a few times, but with no results. I guess there is a reason why the response is always wrapped in an "items" property, but I can not figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you instead of returning a Collections you return an Array?

```
@ApiMethod(name="listChildren")
public Child[] listChildren() {
    Collection<Child> children = getChildren(); //call some method to build the collection
    return children.toArray();
}
```

And you can always create your own ApiTransformer that create the return that you want without the "items" property.
More on that on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer.

Comment: I tried both solutions to no avail. Returning a `Child[]` gives the same result. Extending a `Collection` in order to use an `ApiTransformer` will return a JSON with the following format: `{"items":"transformed collection from my ApiTransformer"}`